# Are HTML tables still the way to go?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, html-table, bulma

AFAIK people create their own table-like-components and the use of the good old HTML tables is kind of "outdated". Now I'm at the point where I would need a table for my vuejs application. I'm using bulma [and the doc states this](https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/table/):

> Table
>
> The inevitable HTML table, with special case cells

The "support" badges below that title state that there isn't much support for it (only variables) and the text itself sounds like "well... since so many not-up-to-date-people want it, here, take it".

Should I rather go the "unordered list" way or something else? Like creating a component to represent a row and a component holding the table together? I'm not asking for vue specifically, but for a rather "modern approach" and how to do something like that properly.

Comment: Try using CSS grid. Its a much more modern approach. That along with flexbox will get you alot further, and allow for nicer vueJS components. Imagine a 10x10 grid. Imagine the hassle of filling it in Vuejs if its a table, compared to if its just 10 columns with 10 rows ;)

Comment: You should use CSS grid structure instead. That's pretty much what 90% of current websites run on.  Tables have their usage here and now, but I definitely wouldn't base my layout on it in current day and age.

Comment: If you have *tabular* data, *absolutely use an HTML table*. The knock against HTML tables has always been about using them as a structure to layout your website.

Comment: The way to go **for what**?  Tables are what you should be using for tables.  If you're just hacking a layout that happens to have a couple rows and columns, tables are not for that.

Comment: @Bert Yeah but what is "tabular data"? Data that can be represented within a table? Because this is what I mean. If I have data that I would need some kind of "table structure", do I use HTML tables or CSS Grid or whatever people are suggesting.

Comment: Data that would otherwise be well represented in a spreadsheet is tabular data. The link you provided shows a good example (football teams and their stats). CSS grids and flexbox are meant for layout out your page (navigation, header, footer, main content, etc). Obviously CSS grid and flexbox *could* be used to lay out tabular data, but that is what tables are for.

Comment: This post shouldn't have been closed. I can only apologise for others who thought otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

The table element is still the correct way to provide tabular data in a semantically correct way in HTML. So if you use it semantically correct it is fine and not outdated per se.

However having that in mind, it might be a valid decision for you to go with new approaches like CSS Grid if that helps you to faster and more user friendly accomplish the creation of new Elements on your website, as the end-user should always benefit from your decisions.